# Read nested array as whole with Utf8JsonReader

Tags: .net, json, geojson, system.text.json

I'm trying to parse GeoJSON geometry definition using `System.Text.Json`'s `Utf8JsonReader`.
My problem is that the `coordinates` property of the geometry definition might be positioned prior to the definition of the `type`. `coordinates` can be

- a plain array of doubles (`[0, 1]`) for geometries of type `Point`,
- an array of arrays of doubles (`[[0,1],[2,3]]`) for geometries of type `LineString`
- an array of arrays of arrays of doubles (`[[[0,0],[10,0],[10,10],[0,0]],[[1,1],[9,9],[1,9],[1,1]]]`) for geometries of type `Polygon` with holes and even
- an array of the above for geometries of type `MultiPolygon`.

Thus I am not be able to parse the `coordinates` property properly if I don't know the `type`.
Is there a way to read it as whole and parse it later using `Utf8JsonReader`?

Comment: Please add some code you that someone get what you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I liked to do by using the following function

```
private ReadOnlySpan<byte> ReadCoordinateData(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
{
    reader.ReadToken(JsonTokenType.StartArray);
    var res = new MemoryStream();
    res.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("["), 0, 1);
    int openBrackets = 1;

    bool wasCloseBracket = false;
    bool addComma = false;
    byte bytComma = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(",")[0];
    while (openBrackets > 0)
    {
        // add a comma to separate arrays
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            if (wasCloseBracket)
                res.WriteByte(bytComma);
            addComma = false;
            openBrackets++;
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number && addComma)
            res.WriteByte(bytComma);

        byte[] seq = reader.HasValueSequence
            ? reader.ValueSequence.ToArray()
            : reader.ValueSpan.ToArray();
        res.Write(seq, 0, seq.Length);

        addComma = reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            openBrackets--;
            addComma = false;
            wasCloseBracket = true;
        }
        else
        {
            wasCloseBracket = false;
        }

        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonException();
    }

    return new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(res.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: ReadToken is not a method available on Utf8JsonReader

Comment: Right, it is this [extension method](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/blob/106db44029ca67e207e4c88400537f49c005aa7c/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON4STJ/Converters/Utility.cs#L21-L30)